# Boolean intersection based on connected neighborhood - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, boolean, intersection

Having these two arrays:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,1,0,0,1,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0]], dtype=bool)

arr2 = np.array([[0,1,1,0,0,0],
                 [0,1,1,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,1,1],
                 [1,1,0,0,1,1],
                 [1,1,0,0,0,0]], dtype=bool)
```

I need a sort of logical operation that returns as True any connected feature in *arr2* that is been intercepted by *arr1*. The result should be something like this:

```
arr3 = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,1,1],
                 [1,1,0,0,1,1],
                 [1,1,0,0,0,0]], dtype=bool)
```

I checked logical operations in python and [numpy logic functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html#logical-operations), but nothing seems to work. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use image-processing based labeling function to label the image based on connected-ness and then use masking to get our desired output. To do the labeling, we can use [`skimage.measure.label`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label). Alternatively, we can also use [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) to get that labelled image. Hence, one solution would be -

```
from skimage.measure import label as sklabel

def func1(arr1,arr2):
    # Get labeled image
    L = sklabel(arr2)

    # Get all present labels (this would also include zero label)
    present_labels = L[arr1]

    # Get presence of these labels in the labeled image. Remove the zero regions
    # by AND-ing with arr2.
    return np.isin(L,present_labels) & arr2
```

Output for given sample -

```
In [141]: func1(arr1,arr2)
Out[141]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False]])
```

**Approach #2**

For big blobs, we should look to get the unique present labels before using `np.isin` to be performance-efficient. To get those unique ones efficiently, we can make use of `pandas.factorize`. Also the labeling part could benefit on performance by using SciPy version. Thus, alternatively a more efficient solution for such a scenario would be -

```
from scipy.ndimage import label as splabel
import pandas as pd

def func2(arr1,arr2):
    L = splabel(arr2)[0]
    pL = pd.factorize(L[arr1])[1]
    return np.isin(L,pL[pL!=0])
```

#### Benchmarking

We will use the given sample data, scale it up by `1000x` along both rows and cols, while keeping the same number of blobs. To scale up we will use `np.repeat` -

```
In [147]: arr1 = arr1.repeat(1000, axis=0).repeat(1000, axis=1)

In [148]: arr2 = arr2.repeat(1000, axis=0).repeat(1000, axis=1)

In [149]: %timeit func1(arr1,arr2)
     ...: %timeit func2(arr1,arr2)
1.75 s ± 7.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
226 ms ± 5.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks @Divakar, that's smart. [numpy.isin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) is the key to approach the issue and it's a function as was not aware of. I also appreciate the Benchmarking bit, I didn't know `spicy.ndimage.label` was faster than `skimage.measure.label`, and `pandas.factorize` is definitely needed to prevent label repetitions. Just one remark, I think there is a typo in `fun1`, the last line should be `return np.isin(L,present_labels[present_labels!=0])`?

Comment: @Alejandro That wasn't a typo. Both works, but I added the one that I started off with. That's why added `func2` with all those new methods incorporated.

Comment: Sorry @Divakar, you are right. I just mixed up fun1 and fun2 and got confused. That's perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any other library besides Numpy, I would suggest doing a flood fill on the matrix, which can be done with a DFS or BFS.
The main idea would be to iterate in every element of arr1, and if the element is true, add the position to your stack/queue.
Then for each of those positions you would start a flood fill on arr2 and for each new position generated you have to write an 1 in arr3.
The code would be something like this:

```
from collections import deque
#arr3 start empty
arr3 = np.zeros((5,6))
rows = 5
cols = 6
#here i will use a deque as a queue
q = deque()
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    for j in range(len(arr1[i])):
        if arr1[i][j]:
            #for every true element in arr1
            #i add it to the queue
            q.append((i,j))
#bfs transversal
while q:
    i,j = q.popleft()
    if not arr3[i][j] and arr2[i][j]:
        #check on arr3 to avoid infinite looping
        #check on arr2 to see if it's part of a component
        arr3[i][j] = True
        #here i assume diagonals are neighbors too
        #but you can change these fors to define neighbors
        for ii in range(i-1,i+2):
            for jj in range(j-1,j+2):
                if ii==i and jj==j:
                    #we dont want to check the same element again
                    continue
                if ii<0 or ii>=rows or jj<0 or jj>=cols:
                    #we dont want to access an invalid position either
                    continue
                q.append((ii,jj))
print(arr3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Alexander. Sorry I didn't manage to run the code because `deque` is not defined: `NameError: name 'deque' is not defined`

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add an import

Comment: My bad actually, I should have known what deque was. It works, thanks.